# Do all smooth, differentiable manifolds have an acceleration field?

Tags: differential-geometry

If a manifold possesses a set of coordinates, then it seems to me we can imagine an evolution parameter, $\lambda$, and impose on this manifold a velocity field ($\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\lambda}$) that tell us how the coordinates change with the evolution parameter along some world line. That's what I assume the 'differentiable' means. So, if this manifold possesses a velocity field, $\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\lambda}$, then doesn't this manifold also posses an acceleration field $\frac{d^2x^\alpha}{d\lambda^2}$?

Comment: Existence of a vector field on any smooth differentiable manifolds is a triviality: choose the $0$-vector at each point. The very meaning of an *acceleration field* on a smooth differentiable manifold is, on the other hand, imponderable; can you explain what that means, in a rigorous mathematical sense?

Comment: @TheShepard Maybe you could tell us what you mean by a "position field"? Also do you assume some other structure to differentiate a vector field?

Comment: I am afraid we are still lacking some rigorous context. But, by the choice of words, maybe you are thinking of a curve $\gamma\colon \mathbb{R}\to M$ (that would be your $x^\alpha(\lambda)$). The usual way to make sense of an acceleration is by means of some additional structure, a metric, such that you can define a covariant derivative. You could then take the covariant derivative (by $\dot\gamma)$ of $\dot\gamma$ ...

Comment: "Sprays", that is, special kinds of vector fields on the tangent bundle, can be considered as analogs of second order ODEs on manifolds, which hence may be considered as acceleration fields, though as was noted above this doesn't seem to be very common terminology. The covariant derivative mentioned above is related to a special spray ("the geodesic spray"), for instance.

Comment: @WishYouTheBest - I have the metric. I'm trying to convince a referee of a physics journal that an 'acceleration field' is something that differential manifolds possess. As far as the metric for a uniform acceleration field, its $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -(V-A \tau )^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\sin ^2\left(\sqrt{\kappa } r\right)}{4 \kappa } & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sin ^2(\theta ) \sin ^2\left(\sqrt{\kappa } r\right)}{4 \kappa } \\
\end{array}
\right)$$Where A is the uniform acceleration of the manifold and A and V are constants.

Comment: You're dealing with a referee for a physics journal, so think like a physicist: the quantity $d^2x^\alpha/d\lambda^2$ does *not* transform like a tensor. End of story.

Comment: @IvoTerek - I don't understand your point. How is an acceleration vector not a tensor of rank one? Does not every point on this manifold possess an acceleration vector when every point possesses a velocity vector?

Comment: As other people already said, the "acceleration vector" (whatever that means) does not exist without additional structure on the manifold, such as a connection. If you want to show that what you claim is indeed a vector, you need to show that its components transform correctly. And I am saying it does not.

Comment: I posted the metric tensor in the comments above. Does this not serve as a connection to the tangent bundle? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a closer look at how differential geometers approach this problem, for instance, on page 66 here:

*O’Neill, Barrett*, Semi-Riemannian geometry with applications to relativity. Pure and Applied Mathematics, 103. New York-London etc.: Academic Press. xiii, 468 p. (1983). [ZBL0531.53051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0531.53051).

You can also read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(differential_geometry)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20physics%2C%20acceleration,direction%20of%20the%20%22bend%22.) Wikipedia article, the discussion is pretty much the same.

The setup is that you have a smooth manifold $M$ equipped with an affine connection $\nabla$; for instance, it can be the Levi-Civita connection of a semi-Riemannian metric on $M$. One does not need coordinates to define objects of interest. What you denote ${\mathbf x}(\lambda)$ is a smooth curve $c: (a,b)\to M$ in $M$ (a smooth map from an interval to the manifold). What you call the **velocity field** is the vector field $c'(t)$ along $c(t)$, also denoted $\frac{dc}{dt}$. What you call the **acceleration field** is the covariant derivative
$$
\nabla_{c'} c'= \frac{D}{dt} c'
$$
of the velocity field; it is also a vector field along the curve $c$. The terminology **acceleration** used here is quite standard, maybe the above reference will convince your referee. A subtle point here is that velocity and acceleration fields **are not** fields on the manifold $M$, they are more complicated objects than this.

For computations in local coordinates, check the above references (you will have a contribution coming from, as expected, the 2nd derivative, but there is also a quadratic contribution coming from the 1st derivative and Christoffel symbols). But, in the Riemannian setting, you find this discussed in pretty much every differential/Riemannian geometry book. My favorite is do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry."

Comment: Thank you! That Wiki page is exactly what I needed! Perhaps you could do me the simple favor and say, in simple language, whether or not, for all intents and purposes, a differentiable manifold has an acceleration field as defined by that wiki page.

Comment: @TheShepard: The sentence "a differentiable manifold has an acceleration field" has no mathematical meaning (you can as well ask me to confirm that "Moon has green potential"). What one can say is that given a manifold $M$ equipped with an affine connection and a smooth curve $c$ in $M$ one has the acceleration field of $c$. If you want to use math, you have to accept that it has its own language with its own rules and not every sentence combining words of this language is meaningful. (It is the same with any other field of science.)

Comment: It seems to me that there's a potentially interesting question in all this. We all know that if there is a vector field on a smooth manifold, then through every point there is a parameterized curve whose velocity vector is equal to the vector field along the curve. Now suppose you have a vector field on a Riemannian manifold. For each point in the manifold, does there exist a parameterized curve passing through that point whose acceleration at each point on the curve is equal to the vector field at that point?

Comment: @Deane: Yes, but it should be a different question. The answer, I think, is positive.

Comment: @Deane isn’t it just standard 2nd order existence and uniqueness for ODEs (particularly, Newton’s equations)? Namely, if $F:TM\to TM$ covers the identity (‘velocity-dependent force’… or simply a vector field $F:M\to TM$) and is smooth then for any connection $\nabla$ on $TM$, the equation $\nabla_{\gamma’}\gamma’=F\circ\gamma’$ locally becomes $\ddot{x}^i=F^i(x,\dot{x})-\Gamma^i_{jk}(x)\dot{x}^j\dot{x}^k\equiv H^i(x,\dot{x})$. So, specifying $x(0),\dot{x}(0)$ gives a unique local $x(t)$ (we then fiddle around with charts to get a maximal $\gamma$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo, you're right, but what I had mind was starting with a vector field $F$ on only $M$ itself and solving the equation $$\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma(t) = F(\gamma(t)). $$ Your observation still holds in this case. What I had vaguely in mind were questions like: 1) When do "complete" solutions exist, i.e., $\gamma: (-\infty,\infty) \rightarrow M$ and 2) Can $M$ be "foliated" by complete solutions by choosing $\dot\gamma(0)$ appropriately at each $x \in M$.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you clarified the physics background, I would like to point out that there is another construction you may be referring to which is essential to the geometric description of field theories in physics.

Your “position field”, a curve $\gamma\colon\mathbb{R}\to M$, can be seen as a section of the trivial bundle $\pi\colon M\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. There is a canonical space you can construct from $\pi$, the first jet bundle $J^1\pi$, which plays the role of the evolution space in Lagrangian mechanics. This contains not only $(x^\alpha)$ but also their derivatives $(\dot x^\alpha)$ (and time, not that it matters now). The definition of $J^1\pi$ is maybe a bit technical to include it here, but essentially identifies sections which share first order derivatives at some point (and you latter glue the classes, for each point, just like you do for a tangent bundle).

You need not stop in $J^1\pi$ and you may actually construct the second order jet bundle $J^2\pi$, which amounts to $(t,x^\alpha,\dot x^\alpha,\ddot x^\alpha)$. There is again also an intrinsic definition in terms of equivalence classes of curves up to order 2, but what is important is that there is a way to define a (second order) prolongation of a section $\gamma\colon \mathbb{R}\to M\times \mathbb{R}$ and this gives a section $\tilde \gamma\colon \mathbb{R}\to J^2\pi$. In coordinates, this prolongation is $$\tilde\gamma(t)=(t,x^\alpha(t),\dot x^\alpha(t),\ddot x^\alpha(t)). $$Note that this approach does not use any no metric.

Comment: How is a curve (a map from $\Bbb R$ to $M$) the same as a section of the trivial line bundle (i.e., a map from $M$ to $\Bbb R$)?

Comment: @TedShifrin A section of the trivial bundle $M\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a map $\sigma\colon \mathbb{R}\to M\times\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $\pi_2\circ \sigma=Id_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you’re projecting to $\Bbb R$. I am more used to thinking of jets in the vector bundle setting. True enough, I've even published a paper based on the second-order tangent bundle of a manifold. Very close to the jet construction.

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed, and worth pointing out, the second-order tangent bundle does also the trick. I don't know how prolongations of curves are called there, though.